# Six card(three cards with 1, three with 2) are shuffles and place into two piles of three. (probability)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Six card(three cards with 1, three with 2) are shuffles and place into two piles of three. You have two trays labeled 1 and 2. Starting with the first pile of cards - turn a card over:

- if the card has a 1 on it, place it in tray 1 and take a card from pile 1
- if the card has a 2 on it, place it in tray 2 and turn over the next card in pile2.

You win if all your cards end up in the trays before you run out of cards in on pile. You lose if there are cards left in a pile that you cannot reach. What is the probability that you win?

This is my homework from my school, I don't understand the question anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to enumerate the number of ways this game can be played, identify the number of ways to win the game, and divide the number of ways to win by the number of ways to play the game in total.

Our first goal is to identify how many ways the game can be played. Let's say after you shuffle the 6 cards and deal them into 2 piles of 3, you place the first pile directly on top of the second pile and obtain a single pile of 6 cards. If you turn this pile face up, you will find some combination of 1 cards and 2 cards (let's call them aces and jokers, respectively). You should observe that swapping any given pair of an ace with another ace OR a joker with a joker really don't change the way the game would have been played with that particular shuffle.

This is where we see this is an equivalent problem as asking "How many distinct ways are there to rearrange the letters in the character string AAAJJJ?" You will eventually encounter the formula to compute *[multinomial coefficients](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/461/binomial.pdf)* as $$ \binom{n}{n_1, n_2,..., n_r} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_r!}$$ where $n$ and $n_1, n_2, ..., n_r$ are integers such that $n= n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_r$. Don't worry about the notation right now for the sake of your problem: in our case with the aces and jokers, $n=6$ and $r=2$ with $n_1 = 3$ and $n_2 = 3$ also. So the total number of ways to play this game is

$$\binom{6}{3,3} = \frac{6!}{3!3!} = \frac{720}{6*6} = 20$$

That is to say, no matter how you shuffle the original 6 cards, your shuffle will correspond to 1 way out of 20 ways to shuffle those same 6 cards.

Now comes the part where we determine the number of ways to win the game. Your definition of how to win leads to the observation that the *second-to-last card revealed* needs to be the number of the pile from which the first card was revealed. That sentence definitely sounds confusing so here is the answer another way: If we let the 1-card's be the aces and 2-card's be the jokers, a winning shuffle would be one which the 5th card you see is the number of the pile you drew from. That is, your 5th card revealed needs to be an ace (1-card) to be a win.

Since none of the other card placements matter, we can just use a regular [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) (which is really a special case of the multinomial coefficient). We want to know the number of ways to arrange 2 aces and 3 jokers in 5 remaining spots within a shuffled deck, which is $$ \binom{5}{2} = \binom{5}{3} = \frac{5!}{2!3!} = \frac{120}{2*6} = 10$$

So there are 10 ways to win this game. Since the deck is shuffled completely randomly, each of the 20 ways to shuffle the deck are equally likely, so the probability of winning is the total number of ways to win divided by the total number of way to shuffle the deck of 6 cards.

Thus your probability of winning is $$\frac{10}{20} = \frac{1}{2} = 0.50$$

Notice that this probability is the same if you would draw the first card from the second pile. However, if you were to win that version of the game, the second-to-last card you reveal would have to be the joker (2-card).